# NextJS14 Middleware throws undefined error

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js, authorization, middleware

I use the npm model "serverless-mysql" together with NextJS to send a request in my middleware to authorize my user to my database.
However, I get this error when a user logs in:

```
Error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'slice')
    at Object.connect (webpack-internal:///(middleware)/./node_modules/serverless-mysql/index.js:97:23)
    at async isSessionValid (webpack-internal:///(middleware)/./src/lib/db.ts:100:5)
    at async isAuthenticated (webpack-internal:///(middleware)/./src/lib/auth.ts:18:10)
```

I have already modified the module myself and tried to debug it, but unfortunately without success.

This is my middleware.ts:

```
import {NextRequest, NextResponse} from "next/server";
import {isAuthenticated} from "@/lib/auth";

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
    if(!isAuthenticated()) {
        NextResponse.redirect("/login");
    } else {
        return request;
    }
}
```

This is my auth.ts:

```
export async function isAuthenticated() {
    if (!cookies().has("sessionId")) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!await isSessionValid(cookies().get("sessionId")?.value || "")) {
        return false;
    }

    return await getUserBySessionId(cookies().get("sessionId")?.value || "") !== null;
}
```

And these are my database functions:

```
export async function isSessionValid(sessionId: string) {
    await mysql.connect();
    let results;
    try {
        results = await mysql.query(
            `SELECT * FROM sessions WHERE id = ?`,
            [sessionId]
        );
        console.log(results);
    } catch (e: any) {
        throw new Error("Error executing query: " + e.message);
    }
    await mysql.end();
    return results && results.length > 0;
}

export async function getUserBySessionId(sessionId: string) {
    await mysql.connect().catch(() => {
        throw new Error("Error connecting to MySQL");
    });
    const results = await mysql.query(
        `SELECT users.*
        FROM users 
        JOIN sessions ON users.id = sessions.user_id 
        WHERE sessions.id = ?`,
        [sessionId]
    );
    await mysql.end();
    if (results.length === 0) {
        return null;
    }
    return new User(results[0].name, results[0].role);
}
```

Comment: Is "SELECT *" the complete query? If not, can you provide the complete query. Also, please provide the piece of code where you are executing this

Comment: @ChinmayPant I have added the functions and my middleware.ts to the post

Answer (score 0):

As per your error logs, It seems like the issue is occurring while trying to establish the connection with the DB.

```
async function isSessionValid(sessionId: string) {
    await mysql.connect(); //Error here
    ...
```

Try setting up connection and config the correct way as mentioned [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-mysql#simple-example)

```
// Require and initialize outside of your main handler
const mysql = require('serverless-mysql')({
  config: {
    host     : process.env.ENDPOINT,
    database : process.env.DATABASE,
    user     : process.env.USERNAME,
    password : process.env.PASSWORD
  }
})

// Main handler function
export async function your_function_name(event, context){
  // Add error handling here
  let results = await mysql.query('SELECT * FROM table')

  await mysql.end()

  // Check results before returning
  return results
}
```

Comment: I still get the 
"
 ⨯ node_modules\serverless-mysql\index.js (113:14) @ connect
 ⨯ TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'slice')
"
error

Comment: Ah.. can you create a code-sandbox replicating your issue? It would be easier to get the exact reason

Comment: I don't know whether you are able to use mysql in a sandbox...